# Trying to call jQuery in PHP - not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am checking if there is a Thumbnail image in a  blog post using `has_post_thumbnail()`, if no thumbnail image, a JavaScript script function is called to change the layout of `.blog-post` to `display` from `flex` to `block`.

**To do this:** I am using a JavaScript function with the conditional statement. Like below:

*content.php*

```
    <div class="blog-post">
<?php  /* POST FEATURED THUMBNAIL*/
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>

        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('feature-image'); ?></a>
        </div>

<?php } else { ?>

        <script type="text/javascript"> alert("asdsas"); xfullWidthPostWithThumbnail();  </script>

    <?php } ?>

    <article class="post-article para-text">
        <p id="blog-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <p id="blog-info-text"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> | By <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author();?></a> | Posted In 
            <?php 
                $categories = get_the_category();
                $seperator = ", ";
                $output = '';
                if($categories) {
                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $output .= '<a href="'. get_category_link($category->term_id) .'">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $seperator;
                    }
                echo trim($output, $seperator);
                }

            ?></p>


        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read more &raquo;</a></p>
        <p></p>             


    </article>
</div>
```

**JavaScript function**

```
/*  INDEX PAGE -- ADD DISPLAY BLOCK FOR FULL WIDTH OF POST EXCERPT IF NOT POST THUMBNAIL */
function xfullWidthPostWithThumbnail() {
    alert("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
        jQuery(".blog-post").css("display","block !important");
        jQuery(".blog-post").css("color","red !important");

 }
```

The problem: Currently the error I am getting:

> **Uncaught ReferenceError:** xfullWidthPostWithThumbnail is not defined
>       at (index):155

Why is the function not defined? Any ideas??

Comment: Where is `xfullWidthPostWithThumbnail` defined and included? Also, why do this in JS? Thats adding unnecessary processing on the client-side. It would be much preferable to do it directly in the PHP.

Comment: How would I go about it then? This is in WordPress, the script is added using wp_enqueue_script:  wp_enqueue_script('script_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ipe_script.js', array('jquery'), '2017', true );

Comment: The Script is linked properly, have tested it is working, not the function

Comment: Its impossible for us to see why its not working without seeing the relevant code - we're not mindreaders :) - but the bigger issue is that you are making it unnecessarily complicated. I've added an answer below showing how to do it all on the server-side using just PHP & CSS. Its much cleaner & simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use Javascript to do this - its adding unnecessary processing on the client side.

All you want to do is change the CSS for `.blog-post`, so create a separate CSS class, and apply it if there is no thumbnail.

1. Create a new CSS class for the rules you want to apply
2. Check if the thumbnail exists.
3. If it doesn't, add your new class to the div
4. If it does, display as normal

**CSS:**

Create a class called `no_thumbnail` to add your styles. FYI You should avoid using `!important`.

```
.blog-post.no_thumbnail{ 
    display: block !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

**PHP:**

```
/* declare a variable for your extra class */
$blogpostclass = "";
/* If thumbnail doesn't exist, add your 'no_thumbnail' class */
if(!has_post_thumbnail()) $blogpostclass = "no_thumbnail"; ?>

/* add the class variable to your blog-post div */
<div class="blog-post <?php echo $blogpostclass; ?>">

/* If there is a thumbnail, add it as usual */
<?php  
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>

        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('feature-image'); ?></a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
[...]
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(!has_post_thumbnail())` ? *( Notice the `!` )*

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Good catch! Yes, you're right, that's what I meant, but I hadn't tested my code so I didn't catch that. I'll update my answer to fix it.

Comment: @FluffyKitten that is ridiculously simple. Can't believe I was thinking JavaScript JavaScript JavaScript. Php is enough for this. New to this, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! You should try to do as much processing as you can server side in the PHP (as long as it makes sense), doing it in JS on the client side just adds to the processing required after the page is downloaded and can slow down the page, which no one wants! :)

Answer (score -1):

you should do in this way 
   $("".blog-post"").css("display","block !important");